# How to add an extra value to IN clause in mysql

Tags: mysql, subquery, sql-in

I have an In clause with query inside. I want to add 'NULL' to that IN.
How can i add.

Here is my query

```
WHERE `e`.`lead_id` IN (
    select lds.lead_id 
        from mortgage_lead_leads lds 
        where lds.loan_officer_id=60
)
```

which gives 10 records. I want to add another record to that In clause. Can anyone help me out.

Comment: If I am not mistaken then you merely need to add `union all` and the second select to get the "extra value": http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp or http://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/union_all.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use a unio with select null from dual

```
  WHERE `e`.`lead_id` IN 
  (select lds.lead_id from mortgage_lead_leads lds 
    where lds.loan_officer_id=60 
    union 
   select null from dual )
```

or an or clause

```
   WHERE `e`.`lead_id` IN 
  (select lds.lead_id from mortgage_lead_leads lds 
    where lds.loan_officer_id=60 ) or `e`.`lead_id` is null
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to add it to the IN list:

```
WHERE (`e`.`lead_id` IN (select lds.lead_id from mortgage_lead_leads lds
                         where lds.loan_officer_id=60)
       OR `e`.`lead_id` is null)
```

please pay attention at brackets - it might be important if you are going to add another "AND condition" statements...